# AES_cfb128_encrypt doesn't decrypt all bytes in encrypted file

Tags: c++, openssl, aes

So I am using the following code in C++ with Openssl.
I got this from another SO thread.

```
int bytes_read, bytes_written;


 unsigned char indata[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
  unsigned char outdata[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];

  /* ckey and ivec are the two 128-bits keys necesary to
  en- and recrypt your data.  Note that ckey can be
  192 or 256 bits as well */
  unsigned char ckey[] = "thiskeyisverybad";
  unsigned char ivec[] = "dontusethisinput";

  /* data structure that contains the key itself */
  AES_KEY key;

  /* set the encryption key */
  AES_set_encrypt_key(ckey, 128, &key);

  /* set where on the 128 bit encrypted block to begin encryption*/
  int num = 0;

  FILE *ifp = fopen("out.txt", "r");
  FILE *ofp = fopen("orig.txt", "w");

  while (true) {
    bytes_read = fread(indata, 1, AES_BLOCK_SIZE, ifp);

    AES_cfb128_encrypt(indata, outdata, bytes_read, &key, ivec, &num, 
      AES_DECRYPT); //or AES_DECRYPT

    bytes_written = fwrite(outdata, 1, bytes_read, ofp);
    if (bytes_read < AES_BLOCK_SIZE) {
      std::cout << bytes_read << std::endl;
      break;
    }
  }

  fclose(ifp);
  fclose(ofp);
```

What I am doing is encrypting a file 'test.txt' by passing `AES_ENCRYPT` to `AES_set_encrypt_key` first and then trying to decrypt the same file. The encrypted file is stored as out.txt.

I decrypt by using the code above. My issue is that the decrypted file seems to only decrypt 454 bytes of data. It correctly decrypts the data but not all of it. I tried a test file < 454 bytes which worked fine but using 8kb file, 14kb file etc always results in only 454 bytes being decrypted. However, the size of the encrypted file is correct (ie ~14kb encrypted file for 14kb test file).

Making the 'ivec' an empty strings allows me to decrypt 545 bytes encrypted text instead.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I managed to find a solution after looking through some open source implementations.

The issue is I was using fopen to read/write as text rather than read/write as binary.

The fix:

```
  FILE *ifp = fopen("out.txt", "rb");
  FILE *ofp = fopen("orig.txt", "wb");
```